# AppBarLayout hiding toolbar on scroll behavior, switching fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

I've implemented a `CoordinatorLayout` and wrapped my `Toolbar` inside an `AppBarLayout` so that the toolbar hides itself when scrolling. Most of the app consists of Fragments that are swapped in and out of the `@id/container` FrameLayout as seen below. Some of the Fragments are just `RecyclerViews`, while others are other layouts. I've added `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to the `@id/container` FrameLayout. Heres my main layout:

```
<DrawerLayout>

     <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            >

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                >

                <Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:elevation="5dp"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                    >

                </Toolbar>

            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                />

        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

<!-- ignore -->
<drawercontents>
</DrawerLayout>
```

Now, the `Toolbar` hides itself when scrolling on Fragments with a `RecyclerView`.

The issue is, when switching to another fragment that doesnt have a `RecyclerView`, it will mess up that fragments layout. For example, if I scroll down on a fragment that containers a `RecyclerView`, the `Toolbar` will hide itself (like it should). Then, if I switch to the other fragment without the `RecyclerView`, the toolbar will still be hidden, and the layout will expand into that extra space. If I start back at a fragment with a `RecyclerView` and dont scroll (so the `Toolbar` stays visible), and then switch to another fragment, the content is now pushed down off the screen because of the `Toolbar`.

Heres a screenshot of the issue: http://prnt.sc/a7majo

I also tried disabling the scroll behavior in that fragment using the following code:

```
Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

AppBarLayout.LayoutParams toolbarLayoutParams = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) mToolbar.getLayoutParams();
toolbarLayoutParams.setScrollFlags(0);
mToolbar.setLayoutParams(toolbarLayoutParams);

AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.appBarLayout);

CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams appBarLayoutParams = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) appBarLayout.getLayoutParams();
appBarLayoutParams.setBehavior(null);
appBarLayout.setLayoutParams(appBarLayoutParams);
```

This doesnt work either an produces the odd result pictured at the bottom here: http://prnt.sc/a7mapg

So whats the workaround for this? I've seen a few other questions that were similar to this but the answers given did not seem to work for my situation. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any updates on this? did you solve it?

Comment: Well I ended up changing the structure of the app altogether, but for this particular problem I was able to get a solution by forcing the `AppBarLayout` to expand in certain fragments.

Comment: yes I just solved is as well, the key is to change appbarlayout params based on the fragment each time you commit another fragment, I will post a code snippet as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
protected void setScrollingEnabled(boolean isEnabled) {
    AppBarLayout.LayoutParams params = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) toolbar.getLayoutParams();
    params.setScrollFlags(isEnabled ? (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_SCROLL | AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_ENTER_ALWAYS) : 0);
}
```